# Why does my Mac Numbers file become a folder with multiple files when uploaded to Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

I just uploaded a Mac Numbers file to Dropbox by dragging and dropping from my Mac desktop to Dropbox.com in Chrome. The file become a folder with 7 files in it in Dropbox. Why did this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because iWork "files" aren't actually files, they're packages. And a package in OS X is a folder with some special flag that lets OS X recognise it as a package. Other systems (e.g. DropBox) don't recognise this and just treat it as a folder. To see what's inside a package in OS X, right-click on the package in Finder and select "Show Package Contents".

Comment: Thanks, and if I download the folder from Dropbox back to a Mac, will the folder be properly recognized as a Numbers package?

Comment: I don't know, but I would suspect not. However, if you install DropBox onto your Mac and then use your DropBox folder rather than using the web interface to upload and download, everything should then work properly.